# Show Specific Array Images in Modal Using Laravel & jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I need to show specific image from array images, but I can't do it. Below what I've tried!

**Array Images**

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $product = \App\Product::find($id);

    $picts = [];
    foreach (json_decode($product->product_photo) as $picture) {
        $picts[] = $picture->path;
    }

    $pix = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($picts); $i++) {
        $pix[$i] =
            '<input type="hidden" name="photo_id" id="photo_id' . $i . '">
            <div class="array-images-forEdit" style="position:relative;float:left;margin-right:5px;"><button type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;top:2px;left:5px;margin-left:80px;" class="close-forEdit" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="' . $product->id . '"  data-filter="/reference/eureka/storage/app/' . $picts[$i] . '" data-original-title="Edit" class="showModalPhoto" id="showModalPhoto"><img id="myImage" src="/reference/eureka/storage/app/' . $picts[$i] . '" style="height:120px;width:105px;margin-bottom:10px;top:0;right:0;"/></a></div>
            ';
    }
    $pix = implode(' ', $pix);

    $html =
        '
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    ' . $pix . '
    </div>
    </div> <!-- row-->';

    return response()->json(['html' => $html, 'product' => $product->category]);
}
```

**Array Images Preview**
[image]

Now, when I click one of image above, it should display specific image in modal. But I can't do it. It show all images. Below the result!

**Controller**

```
 public function showPhoto($id)
    {
    $product = \App\Product::find($id);
    $picts = [];
    foreach (json_decode($product->product_photo) as $picture) {
        $picts[] = $picture->path;
    }

    $html = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($picts); $i++) {
        $html[$i] =
            '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="/reference/eureka/storage/app/' . $picts[$i] . '" style="height:500px;width:465px;margin-bottom:10px;top:0;right:0;"/>
        </div>
     </div>';
    }

    return response()->json(['html' => $html]);
}
```

**View**

```
$('body').on('click', '#showModalPhoto', function(e) { // .editUser exist in usercontroller.php

        e.preventDefault();
        $('.alert-danger').html('');
        $('.alert-danger').hide();

        id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: "product/" + id + "/show-photo",
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#dataPhotoElement').html(data.html);

                $('#photo_id').val('');
                $('#productForm').trigger("reset");
                $('#modelHeading').html("Show Photo");
                $('#ajaxModelForPhoto').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Modal View**
[image]

Comment: Hi, you already have image path inside image tag as well in `data-filter` ? why not simply get that value and show it inside modal ?

Comment: Hi, nice to meet you again. Feeling happy for your response. I've been thinking about it. But, still... I have no idea, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `preview` page you are already displaying all images so instead of making ajax call again you can simply get `src` of `img` tag and show that inside modal whenever `a.showModalPhoto` tag is clicked .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//change to class selector
$('body').on('click', '.showModalPhoto', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.alert-danger').html('');
  $('.alert-danger').hide();
  //get src of image 
  src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  //add that inside modal
  $('#dataPhotoElement').html(`<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="${src}" style="height:500px;width:465px;margin-bottom:10px;top:0;right:0;"/>
        </div>
     </div>`);
  $('#modelHeading').html("Show Photo");
  $('#ajaxModelForPhoto').modal('show'); //show modal

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="hidden" name="photo_id" id="photo_id1">
    <div class="array-images-forEdit" style="position:relative;float:left;margin-right:5px;"><button type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;top:2px;left:5px;margin-left:80px;" class="close-forEdit" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="1" data-filter="/reference/eureka/storage/app/abc" data-original-title="Edit" class="showModalPhoto"><img id="myImage" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1f/65/30/1f65303066ef5e14cad11da3c6eeef0d.jpg" style="height:120px;width:105px;margin-bottom:10px;top:0;right:0;" /></a>
      <input type="hidden" name="photo_id" id="photo_id2">
      <div class="array-images-forEdit" style="position:relative;float:left;margin-right:5px;"><button type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;top:2px;left:5px;margin-left:80px;" class="close-forEdit" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-id="2" data-filter="/reference/eureka/storage/app/abc2" data-original-title="Edit" class="showModalPhoto"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e8/c7/c4/e8c7c4d4e14a9e3b21faf3d7b37c5b03.jpg" style="height:120px;width:105px;margin-bottom:10px;top:0;right:0;" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="ajaxModelForPhoto" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="modelHeading">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="dataPhotoElement">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow... as simple as that. Stupid of me. It's not occured in my mind with this way.